# Hamburger icon doesn't show as default icon in toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, hamburger-menu

This is my `setUpToolbar` method . and it's called in onCreate in mainActivity . my question is , why humberger icon doesn't show in toolbar and toolbar show the back navigation icon in toolbar .

this is my `setUptoolbar` method.

```
private void setUpToolbar() {

        Toolbar archiveToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.xmlToolbarMain);
        setSupportActionBar(archiveToolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }
```

and This is my toolbar xml :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/xmlToolbarMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#34465d"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:transitionName="actionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            />
```

and this is my style under the values dir :

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: it just remove the back icon and didn' replace anything(my mean is humburger icon) with that

Comment: Are you creating a NavigationDrawer using `DrawerLayout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this feature you need to add ActionBarDrawerToggle object and sync it with the toolbar.

Something like this:

```
public class DrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

...

private void setupDrawerLayout() {
     drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
     drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
     drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}

...

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
     drawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

This should help.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add that icon by adding below code in `setUpToolbar` method

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);// whatever your icon name
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: yes , i know that . but i see in some code , they dont use icon in drawable like this https://github.com/mikepenz/LollipopShowcase/tree/master/app/src/main/res

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.hamburger);
toolbar.setTitle("");
```

Comment: yes , i know that . but i see in some code , they dont use icon in drawable like this https://github.com/mikepenz/LollipopShowcase/tree/master/app/src/main/res

Comment: Yes, that is in some code. You need to create icon in drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xdpi...

Answer (score 0):

**First Approach**

manually  set custom hamburger icon

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.your_hamburger_icon);
```

**or**

Hamburger is for `ActionBarDrawerToggle`

Then add `DrawerLayout` and `ActionBarDrawerToggle`